# Using CSS / Javascript to completely remove elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a pre-built page for our staff intranet at work which we have limited customisability over. We can add pages etc and are given access to add custom CSS / Javascript (we can't see what current css / javascript is on the pages) but none of the HTML.

Is there a way to remove a selector? There is an icon that is before any links to documents which is added in the ::before selector but not sure what it's called.

I've managed to remove it using CSS (display: none;) but that leaves a blank space where the icon would be and makes the link indented.

Any help would be appreciated - Thanks.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet you can make whatever adjustments you want using just CSS, but as you saw, each change you make might necessitate another change. So it's probably a matter of making your changes one by one until it looks how you want. In this case your next step might be to use CSS to nudge the links back to their original spot so they don't look indented.

Comment: Just use `visibility: hidden` so the link doesn't become indented.

Comment: @eclipsis visibility: hidden still keeps the indent.

Comment: Here's what it looks like [before](http://i.imgur.com/ik15W0w.png) editing it. and here's [after](http://i.imgur.com/7FkUo8l.png)

Comment: I believe 'display:none' hides an element, and it will not take up any space. I think you just have to adjust the margin or padding of the link so it won't be indented.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove a selector"? Do you mean "remove (or hide) an element"? A selector is a part of a CSS rule, or a parameter to something like querySelector.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to remove selectors from the CSS file, yes? Or, are you strictly trying to remove elements from the HTML page through CSS?

If my first statement is accurate, you could try using one of the software items, located here:

http://www.pontikis.net/blog/remove-unused-css

This will analyze the site and go through the css and remove any items that are not being used.

If you are trying to remove an item from the HTML through the css, I would recommend visibility: hidden and then stying the other elements to cover the empty space.

You could also try using clear:both to see if that removes the empty space. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

.remove() it's jQuery.  Attach it to yours selectors.

Comment: I've tried using that, but it appears to do nothing. Is it because I only have access to Javascript instead of jQuery (it's hosted externally and I literally have two textboxes which I can add lines of text to - one for CSS and one for Javascript - I can't see the current CSS or anything they use). Can i add jQuery to a Javascript file, if so how do I go about it?